# Which technique is used to measure huge astronomical distances which are in terms of billions of light years?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

I know what a "light year" means. However, I am very curious to know about the technique through which scientists are able to calculate the distance of various astronomical bodies from earth which are situated so far that it takes even light a huge amount to travel from there. I just want to know how they calculate distance ???

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder

Comment: @KyleKanos: I almost flagged that as a duplicate, but the emphasis in this post is on the most distant objects and I'm not sure that's covered by the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I quote from the accepted answer: *especially Type 1a supernova allow us to measure the distance to even more distant galaxies and out to the edge of the visible universe.* Seems like it's covered to me.

Comment: I am sorry to be impatient while seeking the answer of my question, if I have searched for it properly I would have find the question whose link you posted in the answer. I have gone through the explanation of that question and its answer and now I know the answer of my query. Thank you guys!